# parse querystring in asp.net with mutiple values seperated by colon

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a strange querystring formation that I need to parse. The format is - key=N:1042,B:10,C:200 . I havent encountered this format in the past, is there an easy way to extract the values of "N" , "B" , and "C" in asp.net?

Thanks!

Comment: var extracts = ext.split(','); var n = extract[0]; var b = extract[1]; var c = extract[2]. ofcourse check length of array for null ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, you can also use LINQ to get parsed/split values. Like following.

```
var val = Request.QueryString.Get("key"); //"N:1042,B:10,C:200"
if (val.IndexOf(",") != -1)
{
    var parsedValue = (from m in val.Split(',')
                where m.Split(':').Count() == 2
                select new { key = m.Split(':')[0], value = m.Split(':')[1] });
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Is there any performance cost using linq? This page takes a ton of hits and pulls back a lot of data for products.

Comment: No, it should not have any impact on performance, just new way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

use the Split Method :

```
string key = "N:1042,B:10,C:200";
string[] values = key.Split(',');

for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
              var nbc = values[i].Split(':')[1];
              //Do something with your var..
            }
```

more info here : [Split method MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Very simply:

```
var val = Request.QueryString.Get("key");
var terms = val.Split(',');
foreach (var term in terms)
{
   var pair = term.Split(':');
   var key = pair[0];
   var v = pair[1];
}
```